# JQuery: div class-specific hover not working with bootstrap css

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

### Context:

Developing a "google-calendar-like" hardware booking tool at work using DJango.

- View reservations (their time slot and reserving user).
- Click empty space to create another reservation (bootstrap modal form)
- Click on your own reservation to edit (bootstrap modal form)
- "Calendar" is updated dynamically by querying server (AJAX - GET).
- Reservation data is updated in a similar fashion (AJAX - POST).

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kqQZ.png)

The "calendar" is a custom setup made entirely of divs (I was having trouble with positioning of reservations inside td).

```
<main class="container">
    <div class="calendar">
        <div class="calendar_col">
            <div class="calendar_header"></div>
            {% for time in time_range %}
                <div class="calendar_header">{{ time }}:00 - {{ time|add:1 }}:00</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% for weekday in weekdays %}
            <div style="height: {{ time_range|length|add:1|mul:1.25 }}em" class="calendar_col" id="{{ weekday|lower }}">
                <div class="calendar_header">{{ weekday }}</div>
                {% for time in time_range %}
                    <div id='{{ weekday|lower }}_{{ time }}h' class="calendar_seperator" style="position: absolute; top: {{ forloop.counter|mul:1.25 }}em">&nbsp;</div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>
```

Some reservations can span multiple days (such as Monday to Thursday in example image).  To make it easier to identify such, I want to highlight all the concerned blocks when hovering with mouse.

When creating the blocks I give the the "reservation" class and "weekday_reservationpk" for id (ex: monday_14).

```
function createReservationDom(weekday, reservation, vertical_offset, height) {
    let reservation_do = $('<div>', {
        id: weekday + "_" + reservation['id'],
        class: 'reservation',
        style:  'position: absolute;' +
                'top: ' + vertical_offset + 'em;' +
                'height: ' + height + 'em;',
    });

    if (height >= 1.25) {
        const reserving_user_do = $('<p>', {
            class: 'reservation_text',
            text: reservation['reserving_user']
        });

        reservation_do.append(reserving_user_do);

        if (reservation['reserving_user'] === current_user) {
            reservation_do.css('font-weight', 'bold');
        }
    }

    return reservation_do
}
```

When a "reservation" class object is hovered over, the reservation key should be parsed from object id.  It and every other reservation object with said reservation key should change color.

```
function updateReservationVfxTriggers() {
    console.log('updateReservationVfxTriggers');
    $('.reservation').hover(
        handleReservationHoverIn, handleReservationHoverOut);
}

function handleReservationHoverIn() {
    console.log('Hover In reservation');
    handleReservationHover($(this), "deepskyblue");
}

function handleReservationHoverOut() {
    console.log('Hover Out reservation');
    handleReservationHover($(this), "lightskyblue");
}

function handleReservationHover(affected_do, background_color) {
    const reservation_id = affected_do.attr('id').split('_')[1];
    let reservation_do;

    $.each(weekdays, function (index, weekday) {
        reservation_do = $('#' + weekday + '_' + reservation_id);

        if (reservation_do !== undefined) {
            reservation_do.css("background-color", background_color);
        }
    });
}
```

updateReservationVfxTriggers is called everytime new reservation data is retrieved (AJAX - GET), after it is handled.

```
function updateCalendarData(data, status) {
    logSuccessfulReservationRetrieval(data, status);
    clearCalendarData();

    const reservations_json = jQuery.parseJSON(data['reservations']);

    $.each(weekdays, function (index, weekday) {
        updateCalendarWeekdayData(weekday, reservations_json)
    });

    updateReservationVfxTriggers();
}
```

### Problem:

Everything worked fine until I started using bootstrap.  Nothing happens when I hover over reservations.  In fact, the console doesn't even log output for hover in and hover out (see code above).  If I comment out the bootstrap stylesheet import from the page header everything works fine.

If anyone can help me pin point what the problem is and possible solutions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why it's fixed but it is.

The div containing the reservation had a z-index of -1.  I changed it back to 0 and incremented the z-index of my reservation divs.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯